# AsyncStorage.getItem() doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

When I try to set a value via AsyncStorage.getItem(), I cannot request it back.

```
let tokenData = null;
const getData = async () => {
  let token;
  try {
    token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    tokenData = JSON.parse(token);
  } catch (e) {
    // error reading value
  }
};
```

I have set item like follows

```
const setLoginLocal = async loginData => {
  try {
    let token = loginData.headers.authorization;
    let headerToken = ['token', JSON.stringify(token)];
    let user = ['user', JSON.stringify(loginData.data)];
    await AsyncStorage.setItem([user, headerToken]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Plz include the code of `setItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data you have to setItem like this:

```
  const storeData = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

then you can retrieve it with getItem like this:

```
  const getData = async key => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      if (data !== null) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: i did setItem as follows.

Answer (score 0):

```
const setLoginLocal = async loginData => {
  try {
    let token = loginData.headers.authorization;
    let headerToken = ['token', JSON.stringify(token)];
    let user = ['user', JSON.stringify(loginData.data)];
    await AsyncStorage.setItem([user, headerToken]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: here's your issu `await AsyncStorage.setItem('keyForItem', ItemStringified);` .. .and then use that `keyForItem` to retrieve it

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli I want to set multi values in AsyncStorage that's why I use ```await AsyncStorage.setItem([user, headerToken]);``` ..i have define user and headerToken as 
```let headerToken = ['token', JSON.stringify(token)]; let user = ['user', JSON.stringify(loginData.data)]; ```

Comment: Then you have to use `multiset` instead ... check this out https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage#multiset